# 'Inverted' voltage follower with an opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier, negative, negative-voltage

I'm trying to figure out how I can achieve an 'inverted' voltage follower.

That is if I'm feeding 1V I output -1V, if I feed 2V, -2V etc.

I'm only going for positive tension to negative, I have +15 and -15 rails.

I'm used to the TL072, but any opamp should do I guess.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an inverting amplifier with R1=R2  where V_out is given by:
\begin{equation}
    V_{out} = -\frac{R_2}{R_1}\times V_{in}
\end{equation}

[image: Inverting Amplifier]

Image Source: [OpAmp](https://www.electronica-pt.com/amplificadores-operacionais-ampop)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I had in mind but my power line was wrong so I was confused with the results. Thank you!

Comment: I am afraid - Vin and Vout are exchanged in the expression for gain..

Comment: @LvW Ups.. I already changed, thanks.